# Adjust igraph Layout based on "Ranked" Vertex Attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I have a manually created an igraph as shown below. I have created a vertex attribute labled "rank" of 1 through 4. When the I create the graph I would like the vertexes to be arranged or laid out based on those vertex attributes. So essentially the first 4 vertexes with the "rank" label of "1" would be at the top of the graph, then the single vertex with the "rank" label of "2" would be underneath the 4 vertexes with the "rank" label of "1" and so on. Is there a an argument or method in the layout to dictate location of vertex based on another column?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

g <- make_graph(~ Database+"Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Genetics:
                  "Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:"Occupancy & Abundance":Outreach:
                  Modeling:Mucosome,
                
                "Sierra Nevada"+ Genetics:"Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:
                  "Occupancy & Abundance":Outreach:Modeling:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Panama+ Genetics:"Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:
                  "Occupancy & Abundance":Outreach:Modeling:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Pennsylvania+ Genetics:"Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:
                  "Occupancy & Abundance":Outreach:Modeling:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Brazil+ Genetics:"Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:
                  "Occupancy & Abundance":Outreach:Modeling:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Genetics+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                "Ecophysiology & Environmental Data"- "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                
                eDNA+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                
                AMPs+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                
                Microbiome+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                "Occupancy & Abundance"- "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database,
                
                Outreach+ "Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":AMPs:Microbiome:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Modeling+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Genetics:
                  "Ecophysiology & Environmental Data":eDNA:AMPs:Microbiome:"Occupancy & Abundance":
                  Modeling:Mucosome:Database,
                
                Mucosome+ "Sierra Nevada":Panama:Brazil:Pennsylvania:Database) %>% 
  reverse_edges() %>% 
  set_vertex_attr("rank", value = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3))



plot.igraph(g, 
            layout = g$rank , 
            main = "Network",
            edge.arrow.size = 0.3,
            vertex.label.cex = 0.7, 
            edge.curved = T,
            vertex.color=as.factor(V(g)$rank))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer extends the answer given by Stibu. In order to fix the problems with overlapping labels, you will need to handle more of the layout yourself, although starting from `layout_with_sugiyama` still seems like a good idea. The output of `layout_with_sugiyama` contains a lot more than is needed.

```
LO <- layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers = V(g)$rank)
str(LO)
List of 3
 $ extd_graph  :Class 'igraph'  hidden list of 10
  ..$ : num 106
  ..$ : logi TRUE
  ..$ : num [1:212] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ : num [1:212] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ : num [1:3] 1 0 1
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ layout: num [1:106, 1:2] 24.5 30 37 32 34.5 2.5 44.5 19.5 52.5 32 ...
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ dummy: logi [1:106] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ orig      : num [1:212] 14 24 34 44 54 60 67 73 80 87 ...
  .. .. ..$ arrow.mode: num [1:212] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ :<environment: 0x0000029bbdab4ab8> 
 $ layout      : num [1:14, 1:2] 24.5 30 37 32 34.5 2.5 44.5 19.5 52.5 32 ...
 $ layout.dummy: num [1:92, 1:2] 70 3.5 4 44 17 55 35 25.5 73 73 ...
```

The part that you need is LO$layout. It is simply a 14x2 matrix saying where to place the nodes. You can edit that matrix to place things differently. I will start by spreading out the top row (orange nodes) more and *evenly* spacing the green row.

```
LO <- layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers = V(g)$rank)
TopRow <- which(LO$layout[,2] == 4)
LO$layout[TopRow,1] <- seq(30,50, length.out=length(TopRow))

## Database node looks ugly, center it
LO$layout[1,1] <- 40

Row2 <- which(LO$layout[,2] == 2)
LO$layout[Row2,1] <- seq(20,60, length.out=length(Row2))
plot(g, 
     main = "Network",
     edge.arrow.size = 0.3,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7, 
     edge.curved = TRUE,
     vertex.color=as.factor(V(g)$rank),
     layout = LO)
```

[image: Graph - version 1]

That is better, but still has overlapping labels on the row of green nodes. It is not too hard to see why

```
sum(nchar(V(g)[Row2]$name))
[1] 89
```

That is a lot of characters to fit on one line.
One way to fix that is to adjust that row so that the heights of the nodes alternate.

```
LO$layout[Row2,2] <- rep(c(2.1,1.9), length.out=7)
plot(g, 
     main = "Network",
     edge.arrow.size = 0.3,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7, 
     edge.curved = TRUE,
     vertex.color=as.factor(V(g)$rank),
     layout = LO)
```

[image: Graph - Version 2]

At least you can read everything now. But I hope that you also see how easy it is to adjust a layout. You may be able to make some additional adjustments to make this graph more beautiful and useful than this version.

Comment: Thank you for the info about the matrix lay out. That all makes sense

Answer (score 2):

There are various layout functions that can be used to affect the layout of the plot. `layout_with_sugiyama()` puts the nodes into different layers:

```
plot(g, 
     main = "Network",
     edge.arrow.size = 0.3,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7, 
     edge.curved = TRUE,
     vertex.color=as.factor(V(g)$rank),
     layout = layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers = V(g)$rank))
```

[image]

I have not managed to avoid the overlap of the nodes in the top layer, however.

Comment: Thank you, I am sure some one else may chime or I will update if I can figure out the top node over lap

Comment: There is an argument `hgap` to `layout_with_sugiyama()` that specifies (according to the docs) "the minimum horizontal gap between vertices in the same layer". I have tried different values and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: trying to figure it out as well. Seems like the problem has been discussed here however I don't fully understand the solution provided. When trying ```rescale=f``` nothing appears on the image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194653/r-is-not-taking-the-parameter-hgap-in-layout-with-sugiyama